# creating log4j log file name at run time

Tags: logging, log4j

I am working on an module for import process which can be triggered by various way by user click by schdular etc. and it will go with the phasse of validation and if validation is success than final import.
in order to show up validation error to the user we want to use the log file so that if validation failed we will just pick the log file and show that in a window.
So far everything was fine but now i need to create a logfile for each import job something like
when a job start get timestamp and name the log file based on the time stamp also same time for each job i need to store the log file name for that job so that later can pick the same log file for display purpose.

i gone through various questions on SO
[Link to similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/83918/log4j-log-file-names)
but seems that the requirement was quite different.
One approach which i came to know is to get list of all appenders and den override the name of the file in the code
but since we are in web-application i am not sure about the thread safty and any other potential issue

Can some one suggest me how i can create a seperate log file for each import process instance.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One can achieve the desired thing by some code like

```
SimpleLayout layout = new SimpleLayout();   
FileAppender appender = new FileAppender(layout,"your filename",false);   
logger.addAppender(appender);
```