# Application Logging with Log4j in weblogic server

Tags: java, logging, log4j, weblogic12c

I am using log4j for application logging. And my application is deployed in weblogic server. I use *RollingFileAppender* for rotating logs on daily basis. But,the log file overrides and create *app.log,app.log.1* for every 2MB and date based log rotation is not working. Any Idea how to resolve the issue. Please find my *log4j.xml* below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE log4j:configuration SYSTEM "log4j.dtd">

<log4j:configuration xmlns:log4j='http://jakarta.apache.org/log4j/'>

  <appender name="MESSAGEDEBUG" class="org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender"> 
    <param name="Threshold" value="DEBUG"/> 
    <param name="File" value="/u02/appdata/logs/app.log"/> 
    <param name="Append" value="true"/> 

        <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
            <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d [%5p] %c{2} %m%n" />  
        </layout>
  </appender>

  <logger name="MessageLogger">
    <level value="debug"/>
      <appender-ref ref="MESSAGEDEBUG"/>   
 </logger>  

</log4j:configuration>
```

Answer (score 0):

Go into yours log4j.properties and set :

```
log4j.appender.file.MaxFileSize=10MB // File max size

log4j.appender.file.MaxBackupIndex=5 // Max number of files.
```

About namming your log files, try check this thread : 
[log4j log file names?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/83918/log4j-log-file-names)

And 1 more link that u can find useful :

https://logging.apache.org/lo/org/ag4j/1.2/apidocspache/log4j/RollingFileAppender

Edit #2

I guess now u want to add :

```
<rollingPolicy class="org.apache.log4j.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
                        <!-- The file to roll to, this is a fairly intelligent parameter, if the file
                        ends in .gz, it gzips it, based on the date stamp it rolls at that time, 
                        default is yyyy-MM-dd, (rolls at midnight)
                        See: http://logging.apache.org/log4j/companions/extras/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/rolling/TimeBasedRollingPolicy.html -->
                        <param name="FileNamePattern" value="/applogs/myportal/portal.%d.log.gz" />
                </rollingPolicy>
```

[Log4j wiki](http://wiki.apache.org/logging-log4j/Log4jXmlFormat)

Comment: Hi.. Thanks for info. But, I do not want to fix the maximum size of my log file as the file size may increase at times. Could you please help ..