# Place log file in different folder

Tags: java, spring, nginx, log4j2

I have a single application folder.
Based on nginx configuration i run the same application folder with different host name.
I want to place the log file based on supplied domain name.

Example:
I have a application folder named **base** in webapps folder of tomcat.
and configure nginx such a type that
www.b1.com
www.b2.com
www.b3.com all refers same application folder but with different host name respectively b1,b2,b3.
I want to place the log file in b1 folder if request comes from www.b1.com
and so on.

Comment: Which log file, nginx or tomcat?

Comment: You might find some help here https://stackoverflow.com/q/83918/134894

Comment: @ptomli application log .. (tomcat)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using MDC in log4j to dynamically name the log file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7992473/using-mdc-in-log4j-to-dynamically-name-the-log-file)